# How to estimate this effect?

Tags: mixed-model, inference, econometrics, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model

I have data with columns like this:

`[individual, song, is_after_drinking (IAD), enjoyment]`

- I have observations on an indivudal *J* rating a song *K* (n=800 individuals, m=200 songs )
- Sometimes individuals rate the same song twice but it's rare
- Not all individuals rate every song
- Most observations occur when $IAD = 0$

I am trying to estimate how drinking changes the rating of songs.

I could do a simple regression like this:

$$y_{jk} = \alpha_j + \lambda_k + \beta (IAD_{jk}=1) + u_{jk}$$
where $y_{jk}$ is individual $j$'s rating of song $k$, $\alpha_j$ is an individual fixed effect, and $\lambda_k$  is a song fixed effect. Then, $\beta$ is my estimate. The issue I would run out of degrees of freedom so I don't think I can have all these dummies.

What's an alternative approach?

Comment: Why do you think you run out of degrees of freedom? My first impression is you can estimate all these just fine. The issue may be that I read the $\beta$ as a single parameter and $(IAD_{jk}=1)$ as an indicator $x$-variable. You may think you need a parameter there for every pair $(j,k)$, but I think you don't.

Comment: Wouldn't I have like 1000 dummy variables? I don't have 800*200 observations. As I said, not every individual rates each song

Comment: You mean one for every individual and one for every song? But that's not a problem, you have well more than 1000 observations I suppose. I assume every individual rates a good number of songs (if not all 200) and every song has a good number of raters.

Comment: Of course you can use random effects to bring the number of parameters down in any case. (To what extent any of these models is realistic, random effects or fixed, is another matter by the way.)

Comment: There are several computational tricks for models with high-dimensional fixed effects that avoid having to invert a large sparse matrix, which you can find by searching for that string, perhaps complemented by your preferred software. Note that you have a lot fewer than 160K parameters, sinc $u_{it}$ is usually an error term in such models.

Comment: Sorry, should have been u_jk. But what did your last sentence mean? Should the error not be at the (j, k) level?

Comment: Just replace $u_{it}$ with $u_{jk}$. I wrote the latter out of habit. I meant that if you go the dummy route or the computational trick route, you don't estimate the errors, so you should have much fewer parameters.